# Powerpoint - want to define a color palette that is NOT a color scheme

Tags: powerpoint, color-scheme

I import Spotfire graphics into Powerpoint quite frequently.  Spotfire has its own specific color palette, which aren't the standard colors used in powerpoint, at least I don't think so.

I often must create my own legend or for other reasons match the spotfire color palette, and I do this by entering the RGB codes for the spotfire colors.  I would like to do this one time and have the spotfire color palette always available in powerpoint without having to re-type.

I do not think I want to use a color *theme*, because I want my colors to stay consistent if I end up using different templates (themes).  That is, I don't want to call spotfire default blue "Accent 1", because if I change background templates (themes) I think it will overwrite Accent 1 with the new template's Accent 1.

So I want a color palette that is always available to me regardless of what theme I choose.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was curious I decided to attempt to create a simple Add-In that will allow you to select a chart, series in the chart, and then apply colors.

[image: Screenshot of Add-in functionality]

You can download from Google Docs (*revised link*)

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYMFFPZ29FNmI0TkE/edit?usp=sharing

The file is saved as a PPTM to expose the code modules. Save As a PPAM and load the Add-in; it will be available from the `Add-Ins` command bar.  I have tested briefly and seems to be working.

**Here's the nuts & bolts of it:**

First declared several custom colors as `Public Const` variables. These can be modified using the long value (converted from RGB) to suit whatever you need.

The macro requires that the selection be a Shape, and further that the Shape `.HasChart = True`. There is some logic to trap these conditions.

A user form has a ComboBox that populates with a list of `Series` from the selected chart, and 8 CommandButtons colored for each of the defined colors, will send that color to the chosen series.

You could add additional CommandButtons and colors as needed, or tweak the existing code to suit your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, David.  I've done several add-ins that allow filling/outlining shapes on slides but not charts. This'll be interesting to play with.

Answer (score 1):

You're dismissing themes for all the right reasons.  They wouldn't work for what you're after.  You'd pretty much need to buy or write an add-in to do what you want.

For example, it might install n buttons on the toolbar/ribbon, where n = the number of colors you need on your palette.  When the button is clicked it sets the fill, for example, of the currently selected shape/shapes to the appropriate color.

You could have different sets of buttons for fill, outline etc, or have the code figure out whether the user has pressed, eg the CTRL key.  Click = set the fill, CTRL+Click = set the outline.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  This probably works, but is more complicated than I would prefer to use.  Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Although the slide templates have a default color theme attached to them, you can switch slide templates and still use *any* XML color scheme at your disposal.

Comment: But the problem is that I want to be able to pull up the spotfire colors without overwriting the theme colors from the current theme.  If I switch to an XML color scheme, if my current theme uses "blue" for accent 1 and I've assigned "green" to accent 1, won't all the accent 1 colors change?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct about that, I misunderstood your initial concern.  To preserve colors throughout theme changes, you do need to assign something other than `msoThemeColorAccent1`, etc.  If you're interested in a simple Add-in/Macro, I can probably put one together as an example.